# Handling nested collections with mvc4 view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been struggling for a few hours on a concept that I feel should be simple. I have a Model that is essentially a Quiz with a Collection of Questions and that collection has a collection of Answers. Here is a example of my model (simplified):

```
public class QuizModel
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string TheQuestion { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the troublesome part, my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitQuiz", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    <ol>
        @{
            @Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id, new { Id="pQuizModel"})
            for (int vQIndex = 0; vQIndex < Model.Questions.Count; vQIndex++)
            {
                <li>
                    @Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Question
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        @{
                            for (int vAIndex = 0; vAIndex < Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Answers.Count; vAIndex++)
                            {
                                <li>@Html.RadioButtonFor(pModel => pModel.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).SelectedAnswer, Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Answers.ElementAt(vAIndex).Value) @Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Answers.ElementAt(vAIndex).Value</li>
                                //<li>@Html.RadioButton(Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Id.ToString() + ":" + Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Answers.ElementAt(vAIndex).Id, Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Answers.ElementAt(vAIndex).Id) 
                                //    @Model.Questions.ElementAt(vQIndex).Answers.ElementAt(vAIndex).Value</li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>            
            }
        }
    </ol>    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>                 
}
```

My controller, just trying to debug it and make sure the Model is filled out properly:

```
public ActionResult SubmitQuiz(QuizModel pQuizModel)
{

    return View();
}
```

I've literally tried a ton of different suggestions on my view. It's pretty easy to bind directly to a single value in a Model, I can even get my pQuizModel to have the correct Hidden piece you see in the View. But nothing else in the Model gets populated and I can't figure out why.\

Edit: To clarify my problem, the view is good but the controller does not receive any values in the pQuizModel parameter. I don't have the binding setup properly, need some help there.

Comment: So what's the problem ?? Is your view doesn't filled properly or what ??

Comment: View fills up perfectly. The challenge is when the user submits the answers the Controller's pQuizModel is NOT populated at all. Like I said, the only thing it populates with is pQuizModel.Id because I was testing with the Hidden field in the view. Binding to single properties is easy, nested not so much.

Comment: You mean when you submit the form you have not got value in **pQuizModel** hidden field, right ??

Comment: I guess you'll not get value bcs every time **pQuizModel** hidden field rendered in the DOM with same id. So what you need to do is provide unique id like this - `@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id, new { Id="pQuizModel" + Model.Id})`. try it.

Comment: Please post your pQuizModel.

Comment: Updated my source to reflect the QuizModel, again what I posted is simplified code but should contain all the details needed.

Comment: class `Question` does not have a property named `SelectedAnswer` and you do not appear to have an input for property `string TheQuestion` (in the outer loop)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Razor rendering of your initial page, it's with the model binder on the resulting POST (after they push the button).  The model binder makes certain assumptions about how to map ids into nested items.  Because you're not following the convention as you form your Razor code, it isn't filling the method's input properties.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx for a similar example.